# Window doesn't appear

Tags: c++, windows, window

I have written a small program to create a window. I have made this program before, but now I'm trying to recollect all the things for myself. 
When I was done writing the program, the window won't appear, and when I compare my code to the book I'm learning from, its the same. What am I missing/doing wrong?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <WindowsX.h>


LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);


int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, INT nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hWnd;

    // information for the window class
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));


    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
     wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
     wc.hInstance = hInstance;
     wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
     wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
     wc.lpszClassName = "WindowClass1";

     RegisterClassEx(&wc);

     // Create Window
     hWnd = CreateWindowEx( NULL,
                            "WindowClass",
                            "My Program",
                            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                            100,
                            100,
                            600,
                            480,
                            NULL,
                            NULL,
                            hInstance,
                            NULL);


     ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);



     MSG msg;

     while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0,0))
     {
         TranslateMessage(&msg);
         DispatchMessage(&msg);
     }
     return msg.wParam;
}


LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(message)
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        } break;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: Exactly what does happen when you run it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compare class names:

wc.lpszClassName = "WindowClass1";

hWnd = CreateWindowEx( NULL, "WindowClass", ...

The best way to find such errors is to check return code of every API.

Comment: And why not just #define MY_CLASS_NAME _T("WindowClass1") ?

Comment: @Ajay: Since the OP is using C++, `const char* className = "WindowClass1";` is more appropriate.

Comment: And why not `const TCHAR* className = _T("WindowClass1")` ? :)